# How to instantiate an unknown amount of objects in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a question regarding object creation in Powershell version 5. To simplify my question I am providing the exact Java code I want to functionally realize.

I know, Java and Powershell have nothing in common besides being object-oriented and I don't care how this can be achieved syntactically.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many argument lists do you want to provide?");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        list.add(new ArrayList<String>()); // this is the exact point if don't know how to substantiate in powershell
        list.get(j).add(scan.next());
        // more arguments to be entered
    }
```

The actual intention in Powershell is to parse user provided arguments with Read-Host and build a list of list of Strings containing them. Each list shall contain arguments for one Powershell command.

Comment: You don't have a single question mark in your post. I don't know what you're trying to get answered.

Comment: How can I achieve the functional equivalent of my java code in powershell? How can I instantiate an unknown amount of objects in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
This is the exact equivalent of my java code and what I wanted to achieve:

```
$i = Read-Host -Prompt "How many argument lists do you want to provide?"
$listOfListsOfArguments = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for ($i=1; $i -le $flag; $i++)
    {
        $Private:localParameterList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $param = Read-Host -Prompt"argument x:"
        $localParameterList.add($param)
        #...
        $listOfListsOfArguments.add($localParameterList)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define the question more instead of just posting java code.

But to answer: 
"How can I instantiate an unknown amount of objects in powershell?"

To dynamical add Strings to an Array just do sth like:

```
$a = @()
$a += Read-Host
```

In a for-loop.

If you want to add more than strings, you should read about  [Powershell Custom Objects](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730946.aspx) .

Comment: "The actual intention in powershell is to parse user provided arguments with Read-Host and build a list of list of Strings containing them. Each list shall contain arguments for one powershell command."
I fail to understand how one could think I want to add strings to an array. I described my task very specific.
I need to have a collection of collection of strings to differentiate between the context of the strings. One collection of strings is for one comandlet. They have to be seperated.

Comment: Like I said, if you want to add more than strings, like a list of strings, you should read into Powershell Custom Objects.
The Website i linked explains the way they work pretty well.

Comment: This can be done without creating custom objects for sure. If you don't know how, please don't answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList from .NET:

```
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$a.Add("Hello")
$a.Add(42)
```